# Postgres: How Can a Role Both Have INSERT Permissions and Not?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, sql-grant, sql-revoke

I have a table called `resources` and a user/role called `public_anonymous` ... and as far as I can tell, the user doesn't have `INSERT` permissions on that table.  Here's DBeaver showing as much:

[image: Dbeaver screenshot]

And here's the output of `\z resources` (at the `psql` command line):

```
Schema |   Name    | Type  |       Access privileges        | Column privileges |                                                                                                Policies                                       
                                                          
--------+-----------+-------+--------------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------
 public | resources | table | admin=arwdDxt/admin           +|                   | select_resources (r):                                                                                                                         
                                                         +
        |           |       | public_postgraphile=arwd/admin+|                   |   (u): true                                                                                                                                   
                                                         +
        |           |       | public_anonymous=r/admin      +|                   | update_resources (w):                                                                                                                         
                                                         +
        |           |       | public_admin_user=arwd/admin  +|                   |   (u): (( SELECT resource_authors.user_id                                                                                                     
                                                         +
        |           |       | public_user=ar/admin          +|                   |    FROM resource_authors                                                                                                                      
                                                         +
        |           |       | =a/admin                       |                   |   WHERE ((resource_authors.resource_id = resource_authors.resource_id) AND (resource_authors.user_id = (NULLIF(current_setting('jwt.claims.person_id'::text, true), ''::text))::integer))) IS NOT NULL)+
        |           |       |                                |                   |   to: public_user                                                                                                                             
                                                         +
        |           |       |                                |                   | delete_resources (d):                                                                                                                         
                                                         +
        |           |       |                                |                   |   (u): (( SELECT resource_authors.user_id                                                                                                     
                                                         +
        |           |       |                                |                   |    FROM resource_authors                                                                                                                      
                                                         +
        |           |       |                                |                   |   WHERE ((resource_authors.resource_id = resource_authors.resource_id) AND (resource_authors.user_id = (NULLIF(current_setting('jwt.claims.per
son_id'::text, true), ''::text))::integer))) IS NOT NULL)+
        |           |       |                                |                   |   to: public_user
```

The key part of that is:

```
public_anonymous=r/admin
```

ie. the role has only been granted read ("r") permissions by the `admin` role.

Furthermore, I have repeatedly tried to remove `INSERT` permissions by running:

```
REVOKE INSERT ON resources FROM public_anonymous;
```

Nevertheless, when I tried using pgTAP to verify my permissions, I was surprised to find that it reported that the user *did* have `INSERT` permissions.  When I asked the maintainer why it thought that, he explained that it used the `pg_catalog.has_table_privilege` function ... and sure enough, when I ran:

```
select pg_catalog.has_table_privilege('public_anonymous', 'resources', 'INSERT');
```

I saw:

```
 has_table_privilege 
---------------------
 t
```

I'm not a Postgres expert, so forgive me if this is a dumb question.  Also I should note that I have been using both `GRANT` statements and row-level security policies on this table ...

... but still, I don't understand why multiple sources all say the user *doesn't* have `INSERT` permissions, **AND** I explicitly `REVOKE`-ed them ... yet `pg_catalog.has_table_privilege` still thinks I do have the permission.

Can anyone explain what's going on, and possibly how I might remove this permission (for good)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ACL item

```
=a/admin
```

means that `PUBLIC` (that is, everyone) has `INSERT` privileges on the relation. `REVOKE` that if you don't want it.

Comment: This was driving me crazy, thank you.   And I think you've helped me with another tricky Postgres question in the past too, so let me just say: you sir are a Stack Overflow treasure!